# Python Logging Against Multiple Handlers Not Working

Tags: python, python-2.7

The intention here is to log to:

1. local log file (INFO)
2. console (DEBUG)
3. remote source (INFO)

However my code only seems to write to both console/file source at the same log level so if I later on in my code call sessionLog.debug("This should be a debug line") in one function and sessionLog.info("This should be an info line") in another, both are logged to both the console and the file. What I'm trying to make happen is that sessionLog.debug() would go to the console line. What am I missing here? I understand the remote source won't work for right now.

```
import logging, logging.handlers

sessionLogFilename = datetime.now().strftime('LineGame_%H_%M_%d_%m_%Y.log')
logFormatFiles = ("ROBITLOG: " + '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s')
logFormatConsole = ("ROBITLOG: " + '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
filelogformatter = logging.Formatter(logFormatFiles)
consolelogformatter = logging.Formatter(logFormatConsole)
fileLogger = logging.FileHandler(sessionLogFilename)
fileLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fileLogger.setFormatter(filelogformatter)
consoleLogger = logging.StreamHandler(stdout)
consoleLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
consoleLogger.setFormatter(consolelogformatter)
remoteLoggerIP = "127.0.0.1"
remoteLoggerPort = 5124
remoteLogger = logging.handlers.SocketHandler(remoteLoggerPort,remoteLoggerPort)
remoteLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(fileLogger)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(consoleLogger)
# logging.getLogger('').addHandler(remoteLogger)
sessionLog = logging.getLogger('')
sessionLog.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: The code you show says `fileLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` - do you want `fileLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is that the parent logger (sessionLog) needs to at or a lower logging level than the other handlers. In this sessionLog needed to be set to a logging level of debug.